# AngularJS - Reusable directive and service layer

Tags: angularjs, reusability

My company has a legacy suite of applications for stock market related activities that we are re-writing in AngularJS. One very common use case is looking up a stock/security. Regardless of the application, the screens and api calls are the same. Our goal is to create directives and controllers/services that can be consumed by multiple applications.

What is the recommended approach for componentizing not only the directives (most online examples are trivial and not data consuming) but also the controllers and services used to populate data in that directive? Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This has helped me a lot [fundamentals](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-directive-fundamentals).

Here is the toc:

**Your First Directive**

**Events, Scope, and Controllers**

**Decorator Directives**

**Transclusion**

**Structural Directives**

**Controllers and Nested Directives**

**Directives and Services**

Comment: it could be added as comment

Comment: why the author looks for resources on directives so i gave him what i considered as the best

Comment: then you should explain one of its content..otherwise people will down-vote it..please do that

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you prefer to organize your project.

Assuming the application is going to scale up to a reasonably sized project, you'd probably group controllers/directives/services into feature modules.

So define a module, and setup a base controller. From that, I recommend separate files for directives/controllers/services, and attach them to the feature module

```
angular.module('feature',[])

// file in controllers section

.controller('feature.BaseController', function() {

});

//// file in controllers section

.controller('feature.UtilityController', function() {


});

//// file in services section

angular.module('feature')

.service('feature.someService', function() {


});

//// file in directives section

angular.module('feature')

.directive('feature.someDirective',function(feature.someService) {

return {
    restrict: ////
    controller:'feature.UtilityController',
    /////
    ///// etc
}

});
```

For project organization, I think that the feature based approach works really well as projects scale, and separating controllers/directives/services into each feature keeps your code clean and organized when you're working on a specific module.

I also highly recommend this [pluralsight course by John Papa](http://www.pluralsight.com/courses/angularjs-patterns-clean-code)